# Why is Sarah faulting Avraham for impregnating Hagar?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-lech-lecha

[Breishit 16:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.16.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> וַתֹּאמֶר שָׂרַי אֶל־אַבְרָם: חֲמָסִי עָלֶיךָ, אָנֹכִי נָתַתִּי שִׁפְחָתִי בְּחֵיקֶךָ וַתֵּרֶא כִּי הָרָתָה וָאֵקַל בְּעֵינֶיהָ. יִשְׁפֹּט ה' בֵּינִי וּבֵינֶיךָ׃
>
> And Sarai said to Abram, “The wrong done me is your fault! I myself put my maid in your bosom; now that she sees that she is pregnant, I am lowered in her esteem. The LORD decide between you and me!”

Sarah gives Avraham her handmaid, Hagar, so that she can have children through her. After Hagar gets pregnant, Hagar thinks "lightly" of Sarah. Sarah blames Avraham. Why? What did Avraham do or not do? What was the main problem? From the text itself, all Avraham did was get Hagar pregnant which is exactly what Sarah requested.

Answer (score 3):

[R. Saadia Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon) explains that Abraham and Sarah were having a debate about how to treat Hagar, and the verse just left out the debate part. When Sarah said that God should judge between them, she meant that God should determine who was right in the debate:

> ומה שאמרה שרה לאברהם חמסי עליך מורה שהיה ביניהם וויכוח בגלל הגר והכתוב הבליעו ולא פרשו כי אין אתה רואה בפסוק דבר מלבד אנכי נתתי שפחתי בחיקך וזה לא מורה על שום עוול מצד אברהם לשרה
>   אבל חמסי וגו' מראה על וויכוח שהשמיטו הכתוב כאילו בערך אמרה היא מן הדין שמזלזל בה והוא אמר אין את רשאית [לעשות כך] לדעתי ועל זה אמרה היא ישפט י"י ביני וביניך כלומר יפרש עם מי הצדק ולפיכך נקוד על המלה לרמז שלא רצתה שאלהים ישפוט אותו ורק ביקשה שיאמר עם מי הצדק
>   ופירש השי״ת שהצדק עם שרי ושהגר חייבת להיות שפחתה עד שתשוב להיות מצייתת לה כי כשעינתה אותה ככתוב ותענה שרי אמר לה המלאך בכמו זה שובי אל גברתך והתעני תחת ידיה ומזה אנו יודעים שלא חטאה שרה בהטלת עול בלתי הגון על הגר כי לו היה כך לא היה המלאך מסכים לכך

Answer (score 2):

Rash"i explains there were two reasons why Sarah faulted Avraham:

- When he requested from God a son (earlier in the same chapter), his prayer was only for himself and he didn't mention Sarah. I.e., all he said was that he wanted a son, but didn't specify that the son should be specifically from Sarah.
- Avraham saw that Hagar was despising Sarah, yet he kept silent.